# How to call a function from a custom module on checkout page in magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, custom

Guys I'm learning how to create modules in magento 2, and I have a doubt, how do I call a function that is in my controller in magento 2 ?.
In the controller I defined a function that does one thing, but I need to call that function on the checkout page, how can I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, we never call one controller function into another. The controller is not for writing multiuse function if you want to call a function then try using either block or a helper. Since Helper is deprecated in Magento 2.3.6 you can use viewModel.
If you want to use a block then you have to override the existing block which is used on the checkout controller.
If you want to use a ViewModel then you create a new one and call its function.
https://magemastery.net/courses/magento-2-beginner/view-model-magento-2

**What is ViewModel -**
A view model is an abstraction of the view exposing public properties and commands. It allows developers to offload features and business logic from block classes into separate classes that are easier to maintain, test, and reuse.

**When to use view models**
Use this approach anytime you need to inject functionality into template files and your code does not need to be backward compatible with Magento.

For more help please share the code which you are trying to use.